# Websphere object cahce Implementation not working

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty

Tried using DistributedObjectCache for sharing data between clusters in WAS liberty server.
I have configured things based on [IBM Distributed Map](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tdyn_distmap.html)

I used Method 5 from the link, my server version is 7 and web.xml version is 2.4
After the configurations on my "server.xml" and ibm-web-bnd.xmi, I have used the below code to get the map instance on the application start.

```
DistributedObjectCache dm1a =(DistributedObjectCache)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/dmap/LayoutCache");
```

the dm1a is always null

As the servlet cache is used for caching JSP pages. etc, I need to cache java object so I used DistributedObjectCache 
I am not sure that the .xmi file is getting read by the server, because I have tested by changing the webapp reference in there which was different from web.xml, but no error was thrown on the  server startup

Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Version 7 or Liberty? Not both

Comment: wlp-javaee7-16.0.0.4 is the version we are using